# How add Timber dump() function

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

Can't find any "noob" friendly advice on how to add the Timber dump() function to Wordpress.
I am trying to add 'https://github.com/nlemoine/timber-dump-extension' extension, because I am assuming that is the way to go. I have the Wordpress loaded version, not github version, because I'm working with "Local by Flywheel" as my development enviroment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I did the most beginner like mistake. I just added the 'define( "WP_DEBUG", true );' to the end of the 'wp-config.php' file, not where it was supposed to be.

Shoving it up a bit, solved the issue!